# Should Spring Data Mongodb have nested document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have a project using Mongodb together win Spring Data. I am considering between having references between document by using id or nested document.

```
public class Pricing {
    private String id;

    private String courseId;

}
```

vs

```
public class Pricing {

    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private Course course;

}
```

With the second way, it seems to turn out to be a relational database mapping.
Could you explain which way is correct to go?

Comment: I go with first one and doing aggregation to join collections rather than using `@DBRef`. I have referred that @DBRef is slow, but not having experience.

Comment: The usual approach in a document database would be to put the pricing inside the course (at least for what you showed so far).

Comment: See Embedding vs Referencing in MongoDB [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/data-model-design/).